# Microsoft Excel convert Oct to 10

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can anyone help me please? I need to convert MMM to NN e.g. Oct to 10 I'm not a superuser but would really appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: just tried the customer format but couldn't make any sense of it, I would have thought it would be easy, but not for me! I'm not by any stretch of the imagination a superuser, any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: Tried in customer format to make cell b24 23/10/2014 to convert to month number in cell C4 e.g. in cell c4 =c24, this would return the value of MM, however this doesn't always return the correct value, interestingly, if I manually change it to =(c24) it changes the value to the accurate month number, i've tried to copy this to other cells but it doesn't work unless I manually change it which kind of defeats my objective?

Comment: Select all cells before setting the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Converting "Oct" -> 10, Assuming your cell is ***C137***:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1/"&C137&"/2000"))
```

This will do the trick

Comment: This approach will work, but you may need to tailor it to your locale.  Different locales use ddmmyyyy vs. mmddyyyy, and different date separator characters.  Excel needs to recognize the text as a legitimate potential date in your locale.  For the US, for example, you could use: `MONTH(DATEVALUE(C137&" 1 2000"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Select your cell > Click Format Cells > Change type to "Custom", type mmm in the box that appears and press OK. The cell will then convert the inputted data from NN to MMM.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to convert month name mmm to nn please see my previous post just now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Right click your cell and go to format

Put in a custom format using `mm` for the month in numbers

e.g. 21-Oct changes to 10/21 with `mm/dd` :

[image]

[image]

[Here is the MS documentation on all available formats](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx)

Comment: Hey thanks, having done all of this it only works when I go back into the cell, for example, if I make cell A1 custom format dd/mmm/yyyy and input (23/10/2014)

Comment: @Loz what do you mean go back? You can select an entire column, or row, or sheet and apply the custom format to all of them.

Comment: Hey thanks, having done all of this it only works when I go back into the cell, for example, if I make cell A1 custom format dd/mmm/yyyy and input (23/10/2014) and then make cell =B1 custom format m and input -A1 it works, however, if I then change cell A1 to another date, cell B1 doesn;t change unless I go in and out of the cell? hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Loz Does excel have auto-calculate enabled?

Comment: no it isn;t should I do that?

Comment: @Loz try it. If it's not on, the formula won't recalculate unless you trigger it.

Comment: What an idiot I am, thanks dude, much appreciated! LOL

Answer (score 0):

= month ( 1 & cell)

If Cell: G4 is Jan
when you write
= month ( 1 & g4 ) it will give you the value 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).